# When running --coverage-html in phpunit a test fails when it shouldn't

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I have a test that will always pass if I run `phpunit` but fails if I run `phpunit --coverage-html`.

One of the key points in this test is that I'm testing the ordering. The ordering seems to change when I run the coverage. What does `--coverage` do that could interfere with how my code is being executed?

Versions:

- PHP 7.1.15
- PHPUnit 6.5.6
- Laravel 5.5.34

Phpunit test

```
    public function testGetAUsersInvites()
    {
        $carbon = \Carbon\Carbon::create();

        $user = factory(User::class)->create();

        $user->invites()->saveMany(factory(Invite::class, 7)->make());
        // Users who are a part of the communication
        $communciationUsers = factory(User::class, 2)->create();

        // Save users to the communication
        $user->invites()->each(function($invite) use ($communciationUsers, $carbon) {
            $invite->communication->users()->attach($communciationUsers);
            // Added some messages
            $invite->communication->messages()->save(factory(Message::class)->make([
                'messageType' => 'subject',
                'created_at' => $carbon->subDays($invite->id) // force created date so we can predict the ordering
            ]));
        });

        $invite = $user->invites->first();
        $lastInvite = $user->invites->last();

        Passport::actingAs($user, ['full'], 'api');

        $this->get(self::URL . 'user/invites/list', ['Accept' => 'application/json'])
            ->assertStatus(200)
            ->assertJson([
                "data" => [
                    [
                        "id" => $invite->id,
                    ],
                    [],[],[],[],[]
                    [
                        "id" => $lastInvite->id,
                    ]
                ],
            ]);
    }
```

Comment: What error do you get? You can try --coverage-text instead btw...

Comment: @Bart Any coverage report doesn't work unfortunately. The error is the `assertJson` failing on the ordering.

Comment: I assume you are passing assertStatus(200) which is fine. Then dump your response from `user/invites/list` compare to and modify your assumption json to fit in...

Comment: @Bart Yea, that's the issue. The ordering changes if I run phpunit with coverage.  It works correctly if I don't add the coverage flag.

Answer (score 0):

This ended out being an ordering issue.

When you run coverage your test time significantly increases. This caused my factories to take longer to create which also meant that my created_at times were off by milliseconds than what they usually are.

I fixed this by hard coding my created_at value in my test.

Comment: IIRC carbon has an option for tests to fix the time in a special test-mode so that time as a hidden dependency has less side-effects. This is perhaps what you've done, it's not so clear from your answer you've done (as in code), so this is maybe useful for you: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-testing